# How to access value in std::map reference that is returned by a function?

Tags: c++11, dictionary

I have a function that returns a const reference to a `std::map`. I'd like to immediately access a value in that map in the same statement that calls the function but apparently I can't figure out the syntax...

My words here may not be precise, but let me show a small code example that should explain exactly what I'm looking for.

My compiler is VS2013 Update 4.

```
#include <map>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { _foo_map[1] = 3.14; }
    const std::map<int, double>& get_map() { return _foo_map; }
    std::map<int, double> _foo_map;
};

void main()
{
    Foo f;

    // I don't like having to have two lines to accomplish this.
    auto m = f.get_map();
    auto d = m[1];

    // This doesn't work.
    // error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<int,double,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
    // auto d2 = f.get_map()[1];

    // This doesn't work.
    // error C2059: syntax error : '['
    // auto d2 = f.get_map().[1];

    // This doesn't work.
    // error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<int,double,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
    // auto& m2 = f.get_map();
    // auto d3 = m2[1];
}
```

Edit: I now realize that the line that reads `auto m = f.get_map();` should probably be `auto& m = f.get_map();` to avoid copying the map, and when I do this, the line following now has a syntax error (the same as the `auto d2` example that doesn't work).

Comment: `operator[]` cannot be called on a `const` map. If the key does not exist, `operator[]` inserts a new item into the map before returning a reference to it. Change `get_map()` to return a non-const reference, then you should be able to use `f.get_map()[1]`. The alternative is to add a `get_value()` method to `Foo`: `double get_value(int key) { return _foo_map[key]; } ... auto d = f.get_value(1);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'd like the map to be const so no one inadvertantly modifies it. Do I simply need to access the values using `at()`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `at()` on a `const` map.  `at()` is a non-modifying accessor, unlike `operator[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) has no `const` version, because it inserts new element, if key is not found.

Instead, you need to use [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at):

```
auto d2 = f.get_map().at(1);
```